# Installing revtex4-2 assistance (in MiKTeX)

Tags: installing, revtex

I use MiKTeX and TeXstudio, and I'm trying to install REVTeX. As I'm not tech savvy, I'm having difficulties, and whenever I have searched online for help, all the answers are written presupposing some knowledge. The "README" instructions also presupposed knowledge. I have tried reading documentation to figure out how to do this and learn background knowledge, yet I'm still stuck.

So far, I downloaded and unzipped the file from APS and was left with "revtex-tds". From what I could figure out, I made a folder titled "latex" in a folder titled "tex" in a folder titled "packages" in my c-drive and put "revtex-tds" into the "latex" folder. I went into MiKTeX console into "Directories" in "Settings", and added a path to the "packages" folder. I clicked "Refresh filename database" under "Tasks". Nothing happened, and when I wrote "\documentclass{revtex4-2}",  it said "class: revtex4-2 (not found)".

Let me know if I've done something wrong and what I need to be doing - please & thank you!

Comment: That revtex version should be installable directly online via the miktex console. There is no need for you to manually download anything

Comment: you should not get the files from the aps or ctan, revtex is already part of miktex

Comment: Thank you! I tried it and it works now!